# Borrowing reference in structure

Tags: rust

I'm trying to put in one structure information about inotify events and hashmap with inotify watch id as key and name of the file as value.

```
extern crate inotify;
use inotify::INotify;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Notificator {
    inotify: INotify,
    watch_service: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<inotify::wrapper::Watch, Arc<String>>>>,
}

impl Notificator {
    pub fn new() -> Notificator {
        Notificator {
            inotify: INotify::init().unwrap(),
            watch_service: Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new())),
        }
    }

    pub fn resolving_events(&mut self) {
        {
            let mut events = self.check_for_events();
            self.events_execution(events);
        }

    }

    fn check_for_events(&mut self) -> &[inotify::wrapper::Event] {
        self.inotify.available_events().unwrap()
    }

    fn events_execution(&self, events: &[inotify::wrapper::Event]) {
        for event in events.iter() {

        }
    }
}
```

During compilation I am receiving an error

```
src/main.rs:204:13: 204:17 error: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable [E0502]
src/main.rs:204             self.events_execution(events);
```

I thought the best solution would be to separate somehow inotify variable in Notificator structure with watch_service, but I can't dereference `self.check_for_events();` because I receive

```
src/main.rs:203:17: 203:27 error: the trait bound `[inotify::wrapper::Event]: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied [E0277]
src/main.rs:203             let mut events = *self.check_for_events();
```

I understand the core of the problem: I'm trying to borrow reference by `check_for_events` and then using it as parameter in `events_execution` which also requires `self` as parameter, but I have no idea how to resolve it.

Comment: do you use `self` in the events execution? If not, not taking it as a parameter might solve your problem.

Comment: @Noctua, I forgot to write it in post, but yes, I'm using self in event execution.

Answer (score 6):

One thing you *could* do, although it's not very elegant, is to have your mutable method consume its mutable borrow and *return* an immutable one that you can then use:

```
pub fn resolving_events(&mut self) {
    let (slf, events) = self.check_for_events();
    slf.events_execution(events);

}

fn check_for_events(&mut self) -> (&Self, &[inotify::wrapper::Event]) {
    let events = self.inotify.available_events().unwrap();
    (&self, events)
}
```

I've made a small proof-of-concept on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2adb2226d07a9ac56d7a6a39e57e3053&version=stable&backtrace=0) (using vecs of `u64` as the mutable state, but the principle is similar). It might be cleaner to refactor your code so that some external client can (mutably) borrow the `Notifier`, produce the events, release the borrow, and borrow it (immutably) to process them...

Comment: Okay, I tried to rewrite my code, and now I have `'self' does not live long enough` in second line in `check_for_events` function.

Comment: I think my code might be incorrect in returning `&self`: returning `self` (declared as `&Self`) seems to work fine though: [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=eba3afdc098f5a0ceb1802e0cedbf757&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: `fn check_for_events(&mut self) -> (&Self, &[inotify::wrapper::Event]) {
        let events = self.inotify.available_events().unwrap();
        (self, events)
    }`


In second line `cannot borrow '*self' as immutable because 'self.inotify' is also borrowed as mutable` and in first line `previous borrow of 'self.inotify occurs here`

Answer (score 4):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21906) in the borrow checker ([more discussion on internals](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/relaxing-the-borrow-checker-for-fn-mut-self-t/3256)). You cannot have a function taking a `&mut T` to an object and returning a `&T` without losing the ability to access the object again until the `&T` goes out of scope. You can't work around it due to the way `inotify` is implemented.

But you [can ask the `inotify` authors](https://github.com/hannobraun/inotify-rs/issues/35) to create a `get_available_notifications` method that doesn't fetch new data. This way you can call `available_notifications` once and drop the returned value. Then call `get_available_notifications` (which doesn't take `&mut INotify`, but just `&INotify`) and work from there.