# Why doesn't a mutable borrow of self change to immutable?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

This code fails the dreaded borrow checker ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=81b5445c6ddaa5b089ce27a751e5b0a3&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
struct Data {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
    c: i32,
}

impl Data {
    fn reference_to_a(&mut self) -> &i32 {
        self.c = 1;
        &self.a
    }
    fn get_b(&self) -> i32 {
        self.b
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut dat = Data{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
    let aref = dat.reference_to_a();
    println!("{}", dat.get_b());
}
```

Since non-lexical lifetimes were implemented, this is required to trigger the error:

```
fn main() {
    let mut dat = Data { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
    let aref = dat.reference_to_a();
    let b = dat.get_b();
    println!("{:?}, {}", aref, b);
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `dat` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> <anon>:19:20
   |
18 |     let aref = dat.reference_to_a();
   |                --- mutable borrow occurs here
19 |     println!("{}", dat.get_b());
   |                    ^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
20 | }
   | - mutable borrow ends here
```

Why is this? I would have thought that the mutable borrow of `dat` is converted into an immutable one when `reference_to_a()` returns, because that function only returns an immutable reference. Is the borrow checker just not clever enough yet? Is this planned? Is there a way around it?

Comment: [Limits of Lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-mismatch.html). This is exactly the same case.

Comment: @Stargateur: I don't think the 'desugared' code is meant to compile; it is just for illustration.

Comment: @Stargateur: No it does not help. It is necessary to limit the lifetime of the `loan` https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fc564b89ff4fa44ae5463d7f407e88ca&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: @aSpex: Ah yes, that does seem to be the same. But the docs don't suggest a solution or workaround?

Comment: Oh indeed "This program is clearly correct according to the reference semantics we actually care about, but the lifetime system is too coarse-grained to handle that.". So the only solution is to use a independent scope. @aSpex You should post an answer.

Comment: I'm not good at English. So if someone wants to post an answer please feel free

Answer (score 5):

Lifetimes are separate from whether a reference is mutable or not.  Working through the code:

```
fn reference_to_a(&mut self) -> &i32
```

Although the lifetimes have been elided, this is equivalent to:

```
fn reference_to_a<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a i32
```

i.e. the input and output lifetimes are the same.  That's the only way to assign lifetimes to a function like this (unless it returned an `&'static` reference to global data), since you can't make up the output lifetime from nothing.

That means that if you keep the return value alive by saving it in a variable, you're keeping the `&mut self` alive too.

Another way of thinking about it is that the `&i32` is a sub-borrow of `&mut self`, so is only valid until that expires.

As @aSpex points out, this is [covered in the nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-mismatch.html).

Comment: Thanks, so is there a solution or workaround? Will non-lexical lifetimes fix it?

Comment: I don't think there's a workaround other than splitting the mutation into a separate method call. It's not a lexical lifetime thing; the `&i32` is borrowed *from* `&mut self` so they're fundamentally tied together.

Comment: @Timmmm the OP example works as-is with NLL enabled.

Comment: _"example works as-is with NLL enabled"_ only because the `aref` is unused. If you use it, like `println!("{} {}", aref, dat.get_b());` then NLL won't be of any help, as @ChrisEmerson explained.

Comment: Is there a reason why rust couldn't be extended to allow this, or even why it would be difficult to allow this. For example, why wouldn't rust be able to "demote" the mutable borrow of self to an immutable borrow of self when returned. That way, it would work (since you can have multiple immutable borrows of the same thing).

Answer (score 2):

***Why is this an error:*** While a more precise explanation was already given by @Chris some 2.5 years ago, you can read `fn reference_to_a(&mut self) -> &i32` as a declaration that:

> “I want to exclusively borrow `self`, then return a shared/immutable reference which lives as long as the original exclusive borrow” <sub>*([source](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/return-immutable-reference-taking-mutable-reference-to-self/16970/7))*</sub>

Apparently [it can even prevent me from shooting myself in the foot](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/blog-post-nested-method-calls-via-two-phase-borrowing/4886/33).

***Is the borrow checker just not clever enough yet? Is this planned?***

There's still no way to express "I want to exclusively borrow self for the duration of the call, and return a shared reference with a *separate lifetime*". It is [mentioned in the nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-mismatch.html) as @aSpex pointed out, and is listed among the [Things Rust doesn’t let you do](https://medium.com/@GolDDranks/things-rust-doesnt-let-you-do-draft-f596a3c740a5#3b78) as of late 2018.

I couldn't find specific plans to tackle this, as previously [other borrow checker improvements were deemed higher priority](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/relaxing-the-borrow-checker-for-fn-mut-self-t/3256/21). The idea about allowing separate read/write "lifetime roles" (`Ref2<'r, 'w>`) was [mentioned in the NLL RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2094-nll.md#different-lifetime-roles), but no-one has made it into an RFC of its own, as far as I can see.

***Is there a way around it?*** Not really, but depending on the reason you needed this in the first place, other ways of structuring the code may be appropriate:

- You can return a copy/clone instead of the reference
- Sometimes you can split a `fn(&mut self) -> &T` into two, one taking `&mut self` and another returning `&T`, [as suggested by @Chris here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190333/mutable-borrow-of-self-doesnt-change-to-immutable#comment69594591_41194414)
- As is often the case in Rust, rearranging your structs [to be "data-oriented" rather than "object-oriented"](https://kyren.github.io/rustconf_2018_slides/index.html) can help
- You can return a shared reference from the method: `fn(&mut self) -> (&Self, &T)` ([from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38080934/1026))
- You can make the fn take a shared `&self` reference and use [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) (i.e. define the parts of `Self` that need to be mutated as `Cell<T>` or `RefCell<T>`). This may feel like cheating, but it's actually appropriate, e.g. when the reason you need mutability as an [implementation detail of a logically-immutable method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/#implementation-details-of-logically-immutable-methods). After all we're making a method take a `&mut self` [not because it mutates parts of `self`, but](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/return-immutable-reference-taking-mutable-reference-to-self/16970/10) to [make it known to the caller so that it's possible to reason about which values can change in a complex program](https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2015/05/17/the-problem-with-shared-mutability/).