# How do I safely use an object while it is mutably borrowed?

Tags: rust, immutability, borrow-checker

I have [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=075e10f188f6d73c3be762df52dd8444&version=stable&backtrace=0):

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicIsize, Ordering};

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Worker {
    work: Vec<u32>,
    progress: AtomicIsize,
}

impl Worker {
    fn do_work(&mut self) {
        self.work.push(0u32);
        self.progress.store(self.progress.load(Ordering::SeqCst) + 1, Ordering::SeqCst);
    }
    fn get_progress(&self) -> isize {
        self.progress.load(Ordering::SeqCst)
    }
}

pub struct Manager<CB: FnMut()> {
    cb: CB
}

impl<CB: FnMut()> Manager<CB> {
    fn do_a_bit_more_work(&mut self) {
        (self.cb)();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut worker = Worker::default();

    let mut manager = Manager {
        cb: || worker.do_work()
    };

    while worker.get_progress() < 100 {
        manager.do_a_bit_more_work();
    }
}
```

That is, I have some manager that calls a callback to do some work. I want the callback to be `Worker::do_work()` and that function updates the members of `Worker` so it needs `&mut self`. However once I pass `worker.do_work()` to the manager it means `worker` is mutably borrowed so I can never use it again.

I want to use it again to check progress, and maybe change its behaviour. I can use atomic operations and mutexes and so on to try to make sure it is safe to do so, but how can I tell Rust to allow this without getting the `cannot borrow X as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable` error?

I'm guessing it is something to do with `Cell` or `RefCell` but I can't work it out.

Comment: please show the work you have done with `Cell` and `RefCell`. There is a lot of documentation on those types in the [std::cell](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html) docs.

Comment: The direct answer to your stated question (*How do I tell Rust it is ok to borrow self as immutable when it is already borrowed mutably?*) is: **you don't**. It is inherently unsafe to do so.

Comment: @ker: I get the idea of `Cell` and `RefCell`, I'm just not sure how best to apply them to this case. The documentation doesn't really help with that.

Comment: A (non-)compilable minimal example that I believe demonstrates the exact error the OP is getting: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=075e10f188f6d73c3be762df52dd8444&version=stable&backtrace=0). Despite the obvious shortcomings of the OP's code, I'd also be curious how to structure things so that the `while` loop becomes possible.

Comment: @user4815162342: Thanks! I'll add it to the question.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Ok badly worded, but how do make the example work in any case?

Comment: Example code would be less confusing if it avoided gratuitous use of atomic types in an otherwise mutable data structure. Note that `x.store(x.load() + 1)` is an antipattern that defeats the purpose of atomic in *any* language.

Comment: Linked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190333/mutable-borrow-of-self-doesnt-change-to-immutable

Comment: @Stargateur: I'm not sure that is the same issue. In this case `player` really is legitimately mutably borrowed since `manager.do_a_bit_more_work()` really does mutate it.

Comment: @Stargateur: Ha that is cheating! You can't create an entirely new `Manager` on each loop. It has some (omitted in the example) state.

Comment: @Stargateur: Well technically `fn main() {}` is equivalent since the code doesn't actually do anything! I think the example is clear enough without being overly complex.

Comment: @Timmmm I don't understand why you want a `Manager` of `Worker`, if after you use `Worker` yourself in the `while`. Why don't you put `Worker` in the `struct` Manager?

Comment: @Stargateur: This is a simplification of my actual code. I think it makes my question clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simpler example I'm going to use:

```
struct Manager<F> {
    cb: F,
}
impl<F> Manager<F>
    where F: FnMut()
{
    fn do_a_bit_more_work(&mut self) { (self.cb)() }
}

struct Worker;
impl Worker {
    fn do_work(&mut self) {}
    fn get_progress(&self) -> u8 { 100 }
}

fn main() {
    let mut worker = Worker;

    let mut manager = Manager {
        cb: || worker.do_work()
    };

    while worker.get_progress() < 100 {
        manager.do_a_bit_more_work();
    }
}
```

Adding `RefCell` allows it to compile:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let worker = RefCell::new(Worker);

    let mut manager = Manager {
        cb: || worker.borrow_mut().do_work()
    };

    while worker.borrow().get_progress() < 100 {
        manager.do_a_bit_more_work();
    }
}
```

Now the closure borrows an immutable reference of the `RefCell<Worker>` and checking for an exclusive mutable borrow moves from compile time to runtime.

Of course, `RefCell` isn't required to *solve the problem*, but avoiding `RefCell` does mean you have to look at the problem from a different direction. One solution is instead of keeping the `Worker`, give it to the `Manager`. Then borrow it back as needed:

```
trait DoWork {
    fn do_work(&mut self);
}

struct Manager<T> {
    work: T,
}

impl<T> Manager<T>
    where T: DoWork
{
    fn do_a_bit_more_work(&mut self) {
        self.work.do_work()
    }

    fn inspect<F, U>(&self, mut f: F) -> U
        where F: FnMut(&T) -> U
    {
        f(&self.work)
    }

    // Optionally
    // fn inspect_mut<F, U>(&mut self, mut f: F) -> U
    //    where F: FnMut(&mut T) -> U
    // {
    //     f(&mut self.work)
    // }

    fn into_inner(self) -> T {
        self.work
    }
}

struct Worker;
impl Worker {
    fn get_progress(&self) -> u8 {
        100
    }
}

impl DoWork for Worker {
    fn do_work(&mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let worker = Worker;

    let mut manager = Manager { work: worker };

    while manager.inspect(|w| w.get_progress()) < 100 {
        manager.do_a_bit_more_work();
    }

    let worker = manager.into_inner();
}
```